# If I remote wipe my iPhone, can I still locate it remotely?

Tags: iphone, find-my-iphone

If I lose my iPhone, and I use remote wipe to prevent my confidential data from being stolen, then can I still use Find My iPhone to locate it on a map?  I'm assuming not (since it resets to factory settings), but I wanted to double-check.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, you won't be able to. It tells you that on [icloud.com](http://icloud.com/), before wiping your iPhone:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Currently, an erased iPhone cannot be located according to these Apple KB articles.

- [iCloud: Erase your device](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH2701) (Feb 4, 2015)
- [If your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch is lost or stolen](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201472) (Mar 22, 2015)

> Important: Before you erase your device, try to locate it or play a sound on it. After you erase it, you can’t use Find My iPhone to do either.

> 4. Erase your device. To prevent anyone else from accessing the data on your missing device, you can erase it remotely. When you erase your device, all of your information (including credit or debit cards for Apple Pay) will be deleted from the device, and you won't be able to locate it using Find My iPhone. After you erase a device, you can't track it. If you remove the device from your account after you erase it, Activation Lock will be turned off. This allows another person to activate and use your device.

Comment: Does wiping the device also retroactively delete the location data that will now grow stale in the iCloud and iOS Find My iPhone apps?

Comment: @bmike Fortunately, I've never had to erase a device using Find My iPhone. I guess I could try it in the name of science though?

Comment: If you don't - I'll try it on an iPod touch later and edit in the answer :-)