# Can Find My iPhone still locate a device if it is restored with DFU mode?

Tags: iphone, ios, find-my-iphone

How does this work? You can restore phones in DFU mode but you're faced with Activation Lock if you have enabled it. Will you still be able to locate it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't locate the device with an active Activation Lock.

Any restored device can't be located with Find My iPhone:

- [If I remote wipe my iPhone, can I still locate it remotely?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34861/if-i-remote-wipe-my-iphone-can-i-still-locate-it-remotely)

Comment: I thought the question was meant if someone else tries to reset the phone e.g. through DFU mode, can you still locate it?

Comment: @Gabkano Yes, that's what this answer answers. DFU restore activates Activation Lock, as mentioned in the question, therefore the device can't be tracked any more.

Comment: and that's also possible in lost mode?