# iPhone disappear from Find My iPhone

Tags: find-my-iphone

My iphone6 (iOS8.3) was stolen in Vietnam during my holiday and I've activated lost mode half an hour later and erase iphone later on. The erased action was pending for about 36 hours and now the device is not showing on find my iphone at all (and I did not remove it from icloud).

1. I don't see it in find my iphone anymore, does it mean the thief(s) restored and remove my icloud from the device?
2. Or does it mean the phone has been wipe off? I didn't get the email notification saying my phone is erased though.

I don't think I would ever get back the phone, just wanted to make sure all the info on my phone is being erased completely.

I tried to look around for answers but can't seem to find it, if there is already similar article would be great if you could point me the link.

Thanks!

Comment: You erased it - therefore removed its ability to be tracked. It will still be activation locked, so it's a brick to its current holder. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34861/if-i-remote-wipe-my-iphone-can-i-still-locate-it-remotely

Comment: But the device is not showing in my Find My iPhone anymore. Does 'erased iPhone' remove the device from my icloud?

Comment: not sure - don't think it should

Comment: Apple really should warn you not to erase the phone if you still want to track it.  An "Are you sure" type dialog (with additional words) would be perfect.  Actually an even more perfect would be an erase function that wiped the data on the phone but still allowed tracking.

Answer (score -1):

Basically you should be able to use Find My iPhone to locate your device and take additional actions that can help you recover it and keep your data secure. It is possible that the GPS locator has been disabled.

Comment: Not once erased.